# Delete Lines from table if the sum of multiple lines is Nil (based on criteria)

Tags: mysql, sql, row, remove-if

I'm working with the following table where you can get activity from customer purchases.

| DateOfActivity | CustomerReference | Reference Line | Description | Receivable Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24/10/2022 | CUST567 | 1 | Credit Purchase | 20,000 |
| 24/10/2022 | CUST567 | 4 | Credit Purchase | 10,000 |
| 24/10/2022 | CUST555 | 2 | Credit Purchase | 50,000 |
| 27/10/2022 | CUST555 | 2 | Contract Sign | 0 |
| 27/10/2022 | CUST567 | 4 | Contract Sign | 0 |
| 27/10/2022 | CUST567 | 1 | Contract Sign | 0 |
| 27/10/2022 | CUST567 | 4 | Repayment | -3,500 |
| 27/10/2022 | CUST567 | 4 | Repayment | -6,500 |
| 13/11/2022 | CUST567 | 1 | Repayment | -10,000 |
| 13/11/2022 | CUST567 | 1 | Repayment | -2,000 |
| 18/11/2022 | CUST567 | 1 | Contract Sign | 0 |
| 18/11/2022 | CUST567 | 1 | Repayment | -3,000 |

I'm using the following query to extract the above table:

```
Select
DateOfActivity, CustomerReferencce, ReferenceLine, Description, ReceivableAmount
From 'Table A'
Where
DateOfActivity >= '2022-09-01'
Group by
DateOfActivity
```

As you can see that the table will only get bigger because more customer activity is being added. How can I change my query so the customers who have fully paid their receivable amount don't show up in this table?

The result from the above script change that I am expecting is as follows:

| DateOfActivity | CustomerReference | Reference Line | Description | Receivable Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24/10/2022 | CUST567 | 1 | Credit Purchase | 20,000 |
| 24/10/2022 | CUST555 | 2 | Credit Purchase | 50,000 |
| 27/10/2022 | CUST555 | 2 | Contract Sign | 0 |
| 27/10/2022 | CUST567 | 1 | Contract Sign | 0 |
| 13/11/2022 | CUST567 | 1 | Repayment | -10,000 |
| 13/11/2022 | CUST567 | 1 | Repayment | -2,000 |
| 18/11/2022 | CUST567 | 1 | Contract Sign | 0 |
| 18/11/2022 | CUST567 | 1 | Repayment | -3,000 |

**CUST567 Reference Line 4** has been removed because the sum of his Credit Purchase + Contract Sign + Repayment = $0. All other Customer rows are still showing up.

How can edit the query so this is done automatically for Large data? Please note the following assumptions:

- Customer Reference for multiple customers can be the same or different (for example in the above example, CUST567 has two Reference Lines 1 & 4. However, CUST555 only has one reference Line 2.
- The data is removed for Customers based on the Receivable amount coming down to Nil (so all rows for that CustomerReference & Reference Line are removed)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You are taking about "deleting lines" from your table, but you haven't shown any delete command. So do you really want do delete data or do you only want to create a query which doesn't show this data?

Comment: It's more about "excluding the rows" with which the sum of Receivable value for that particular Customer Reference and Reference Line is Nil. So it's more about this data not showing up (not deleting the data). Apologies for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand the question, we need to build the sum of the amounts grouped by the reference line. So this query will get those reference lines having this sum of amounts = 0:

```
SELECT 
ReferenceLine
FROM tableA
GROUP BY ReferenceLine
HAVING SUM(ReceivableAmount) = 0;
```

Then, we can use this query as a subquery and fetch all other entries not having such a reference line:

```
SELECT 
DateOfActivity, CustomerReference, ReferenceLine,
Description, ReceivableAmount
FROM tableA
WHERE ReferenceLine NOT IN 
(SELECT 
ReferenceLine
FROM tableA
GROUP BY ReferenceLine
HAVING SUM(ReceivableAmount) = 0);
```

This will produce the expected outcome.

We could of course also use `IN` and amount <> 0 instead of `NOT IN` and amount = 0:

```
SELECT 
DateOfActivity, CustomerReference, ReferenceLine,
Description, ReceivableAmount
FROM tableA
WHERE ReferenceLine IN 
(SELECT 
ReferenceLine
FROM tableA
GROUP BY ReferenceLine
HAVING SUM(ReceivableAmount) <> 0);
```

This will create the same result. Just take what you prefer.

Try out: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dt7JdppB)

An important note: In your question and comments, you are talking about the sum for the reference line is "nil" or "null". This is untrue. It is **zero**.

`NULL` or `NIL` would mean there is no amount, so this is something completely different!

All your amounts are `NOT NULL` and the sum of them is also `NOT NULL`, but **zero** for reference line 4.

**EDIT**: If it should also be grouped by CustomerReference, we can extend the previous queries like this:

```
SELECT 
DateOfActivity, CustomerReference, ReferenceLine,
Description, ReceivableAmount
FROM tableA
WHERE (CustomerReference, ReferenceLine) NOT IN 
(SELECT 
CustomerReference, ReferenceLine
FROM tableA
GROUP BY CustomerReference, ReferenceLine
HAVING SUM(ReceivableAmount) = 0);
```

OR

```
SELECT 
DateOfActivity, CustomerReference, ReferenceLine,
Description, ReceivableAmount
FROM tableA
WHERE (CustomerReference, ReferenceLine) IN 
(SELECT 
CustomerReference, ReferenceLine
FROM tableA
GROUP BY CustomerReference, ReferenceLine
HAVING SUM(ReceivableAmount) <> 0);
```

Updated fiddle: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XjQ7RKst)

Comment: Thanks for your insight. However, the sum of amount should be grouped by CustomerReference AND ReferenceLine. For example, if a there are two customers with different CustomerReference but same ReferenceLine. The idea you suggested will combine ReferenceLines for these two customers although one of them might not have Zero Receivable amount. Is it possible to edit your query so we can get Sum of amounts grouped by CustomerReference AND ReferenceLines? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jonas, but the query is not working as 'IN' must have only one output column (this is the error message I'm getting). Can you please assist me with this? Thanks

Comment: @saashe: The query is working correctly, I linked the fiddle example (see the end of my answer) which proves that all queries of my answer will successfully be executed.  If you still have issues/need assistance, please edit the fiddle and show which error you have and then share the new link.

Comment: thanks but I had to use Concat to fix the query. The Function IN cannot have two variables unless you use concat. However, thanks for solving my problem. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve here? Are the references to large data because something is getting slow or something?

I'd suggest you'd want to make a view for your query (google the syntax for your flavour of SQL, but should be something like `create view as {your query};`)

Then you can query that view with an additional where `"Receivable Amount !=0`

You could also make a subquery, i.e `select * from ({your query}) as x where x."Receivable Amount !=0`

But if you've written the sql you've gotten to so far I assume you know that? So is there an issue in terms of performance or some such that's caused you to ask the question?

Comment: I just want to exclude any customers' activity which has NIL receivable value (Receivable Value = Credit Purchase + Contract Sign + Repayment). For example, CUST567 Reference Line 4 Receivable value = 10,000 + 0 - 3,500 - 6,500. Hence, Nil. Is it possible to just exclude all the rows for this customer and any other customers with Nil receivable Value? If so, then how?